# Daily email reminder from website

Tags: c#, email, reminders

I have an Invoice Application in C#, Sql Server 2008.

In this application, after creating an Invoice for a particular client, admin can set daily, weekly or monthly email remainder for the payment of that Invoice until he/she pay that for that Invoice.

So what would be the best logic for that..??

1. Windows Service on the server (may be it requires an access to the server)
2. SQL Job CRON or
3. AT job schedualed on the server

Comment: Why not create a windows service ?

Comment: But for that we need to have an access to the server for installing that service, but what if I don't have an access..?@agent007

Comment: Well, I think you need only data for this which you can grab from the DB. So you can have service installed on any machine having access to the DB server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different ways to do that. I mostly use windows services in these scenarios but a a Scheduled Job would do fine. Also could you create a messaging qeue and add rules to fire off emails. The email code could be in a DLL.